# Removing a pattern from text

Tags: java, regex

I have a whole bunch of text. In between (random) there is something like [7] or [23] (citation references). I just want to remove these references, where ever they occur and keep the text.

If if do something like `[\\[0-9\\]]` it takes each bracket separately and the number separately. How can I match the whole thing as one group and remove it from the whole text?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex `\\[[0-9]+\\]` should work for your case (any number of digits between square brackets).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your backslashes in the wrong place, needs to be this and have a plus sign to allow for multi digit numbers

```
\\[[0-9]+\\]
```